# java.home variable does not point to a JDK Source

Tags: java, linux, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have used java on many IDEs but I simply cannot on VS Code/linux. Before you tell me to just google it/remove my post, I've already read [the similar stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245865/java-home-does-not-point-to-the-jdk), [java tutorial VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial), and  [setting java.home by oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/#:%7E:text=Set%20JAVA_HOME%3A,Program%20Files%5CJava%5Cjdk1.).The actual stack overflow post wasn't even answered even though it was marked solved.

I am running VS Code on windows and running all my coding in VSCode in a WSL, basically Ubuntu for windows. I installed the Java Extension Pack. I installed the jdk in my root directory and defined the path in settings.json as such

```
"java.home": "~/jdk/jdk-14.0.1"
```

As a response on reboot VS Code says

> "The java.home variable defined in VS Code settings
> (/home/myname/jdk/jdk-14.0.1) does not point to a JDK Source :
> Language Support for Java (TM) by Red Hat (Extension)"

Why is it saying this isn't a JDK when it literally is :( Let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, it wasn't installed correctly. I copied the windows installation jdk rather than installing the .rpm jdk via Alien. After proper installation it was installed in /usr/java/jdk-14.0.1, so I used that as the path.