# Eclipse Spring Tools Suite Missing JDK Warning After Java 11 Upgrade

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot

I recently upgrades from Java 8 to Java 11 (i.e. **java-11-openjdk java-11-openjdk-devel**), primarily using this article for reference:

https://sysadminxpert.com/install-openjdk-11-on-centos-7/

And in Eclipse (**Spring Tools Suite 4.1.0**, I updated each of the following:

**Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs** to:

**JRE home:** /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.9.11-0.el7_9.x86_64

**JRE name:** java-11-openjdk-11.0.9.11-0.el7_9.x86_64

**Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler** to:

**Compiler compliance level:** 11

And for each individual Java project, I edited the **Build Path > Configure Build Path> Libraries Tab > Modulepath > JRE System Library** to point to:

**Execution environment:** JavaSE-11 (java-11-openjdk-11.0.9.11-0.el7_9.x86_64)

However, each time I open up Eclipse I get a warning stating:

**Missing JDK**

*The JRE you are running Eclipse with appears to not be a JDK.*

*Spring Boot Live hovers will not work with a plain JRE.*

*The JRE you are running Eclipse with is:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.9.11-0.el7_9.x86_64*

I've tried googling this, but other issues look like they are actually tied to using a JRE instead of a JDK. In my case, it seems like everything is pointing to the JDK. Has anyone run into a similar issue and know how to fix it?

Comment: I remember a similar thing from another SOF post,  Could you check your JAVA_HOME variable, may bet set it to your java 11 jdk folder ?  export JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.9.11-0.el7_9.x86_64'.   Also it's a stretch but  folder name might be causing a problem. Reducing it to "java-11-openjdk-11"  might help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245865/java-home-does-not-point-to-the-jdk

Comment: echo $JAVA_HOME shows /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.9.11-0.el7_9.x86_64 .

Tried renaming the folder, but that didn't seem to make a difference

Answer (score 1):

Mine works after edited the .ini:

1. Quit Eclipse if it is running
2. Go to the Eclipse installation directory and open the file
   eclipse.ini in a text editor.
3. Search for the line -vmargs
4. Before the line -vmargs, add two lines:

   On the first line, write -vm

   On the second line, write the path to your JDK installation (usually
   something like: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\bin\javaw.exe on
   Windows)